# Parsing dates not giving the same value in the other way

Tags: java, string, parsing, jodatime, localdate

So this is the simple code for what i would like to see happening (returning same values):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        String dateAsString = date.toString(dtf);
        System.out.println("Date a String: "+dateAsString);

        System.out.println("String a Date: "+dtf.parseLocalDate(dateAsString));

    }
```

}

And the output is

```
Date a String: 28-01-2018
String a Date: 2018-01-28
```

How should I do this parsing to get the same date format in both directions?

*Using joda time library.*

**Edit: how should i recover the value from the String with that format?**

Comment: A LocalDate doesn't have any format. You choose which format to use when transforming it to a String (as you did by calling date.toString(dtf)).

Comment: Then how should i recover the value in a properly way?

Comment: Reformat the date using the same formatter.

Comment: When you do `"String a Date: "+dtf.parseLocalDate(dateAsString)`, `LocalDate.toString` is implicitly called. `toString` returns `2018-01-28` (format is year-month-date), it has been coded to do so, so there is no way you can change it. But you can parse back and forth as many times as you like, the date won’t change.

Comment: I finally used the same pattern used by .toString() and it was fine